# Visual Studio Intellisense can't find one base class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a puzzling issue with Visual Studio 2017 and C#.  The editor thinks one of my base classes does not exist.  It keeps giving me a red-squiggly line underneath it with the message that the class cannot be found.  I inherit from this class in two places and get the same red squiggly line.

But what is odd is that:

1. My application runs perfectly.
2. I can debug it and step into the derived and base class code with no problems.
3. I can still right-click on the class name and go to definition and it goes to the right place.
4. Both the base class and the derived class are in exactly the same namespace in the same assembly.  Their source files are in exactly the same folder and both are public classes.
5. I do not have this problem with any other class in my solution (which is large)

Here is one example of the inhertance that's giving me the red squiggly line

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Trainer.Core.Interfaces;
using Trainer.Core.ViewModels;
using Trainer.Model;
using Trainer.Sdk;

namespace Trainer.Capture.ViewModels
{
    public class CalibrationJob : JobVm // <-- RED SQUIGGLY LINE UNDER "JobVm" HERE
    {
    ... etc ...
```

When I put the mouse cursor over the red-underlined base-class name "JobVm", I get the following error message from Intellisense

> "The type or namespace 'JobVm' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Here are the first few lines of JobVm's source file

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Trainer.Core.Interfaces;
using Trainer.Core.ViewModels;

namespace Trainer.Capture.ViewModels
{
    public class JobVm 
    {
    ...
```

So I tried changing the inheritance explicitly specify the full base class name

```
namespace Trainer.Capture.ViewModels
{
    public class CalibrationJob : Trainer.Capture.ViewModels.JobVm
    {
```

... and then the error message became slightly different:

```
"The type or namespace JobVm does not exist in namespace Trainer.Capture.ViewModels"
```

But of course it ***does*** exist.  It's right there in the same assembly and folder.

I've tried to find a way to delete the Visual Studio intellisense cache but I don't have any .SDF files and I don't see anything else.  This is a completely C# solution.

I guess I can keep on going as everything works fine but this is bugging me.  I'm thinking there must be some other issue.

Any idea what's going on here?   Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As a test, I let Visual Studio refactor and create the "unknown" JobVm class.  It created a new JobVm class in a nested folder (literally created folder structure Trainer/Capture/ViewModels within that same project).  The squiggle went away.  Then I deleted the new class and folder structure I'd just created.  The squiggle never came back.  Bizarre.  What's oddest is that Source Control shows that none of my project files have changed (not even the csproj), but it's OK now.  If there is some local cache file that changed, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though they use the same namespace, if your objects are in different projects, then you want to make sure any Nuget packages or included assemblies used in each project are running the same version. I have found that if one project is running a different version then you may get the squiggle lines. I have experienced that before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However they are in exactly the same project and the same folder.

Comment: Little late, but I had this happen when there was a conflict in another included namespace making it ambiguous, but it didn't tell me that.